# SQL Server: Are BLOB/CLOB values stored in the row or elsewhere by reference?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does the BLOB/CLOB data type store the actually object (i.e. 2 GB video or 2GB text) directly in the table row or a does each table row simply contains a reference to a video in the database?

This is important because if I do table duplication and modify the BLOBs.

Comment: Objects larger than 8,000 bytes are still stored inside the database but they are not stored "in row" with the other columns in the row. Instead they get relegated to LOB storage (Large Object storage).

Comment: Aside: You may want to have a look at [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).